# Req.secure in Node alwys false

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Im trying to redirect HTTP requests to my site to HTTPS. Its been extraordinarily hard. My code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('req.protocol is ', req.protocol);
  console.log('req.secure is ', req.secure);


  if (req.url !== '/health' && !req.secure) {
    console.log('redirecting .........');
    return res.redirect('https://www.example.net/catch');

  }
  next();
});


app.get('/catch', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/health', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});


app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

The load Balancer health check goes to '/health'. Every other request that isnt a health check, and is HTTP (rather than HTTPS) should be caught and redirected to https. However, I end up in an infinite loop as req.protocol always returns 'http' for http or https requests. req.secure therefore is false every time and I end up in a loop. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you installed the SSL certificate on your Elastic Load Balancer, so that's where SSL Termination is happening. So your load balancer is doing the SSL termination and always communicating with your server via HTTP. This means you have to check the 'x-forwarded-proto' header to determine if the original request is over HTTPS.

There are several other ways to configure SSL on AWS, including termination on the web server, but SSL termination on the ELB is the generally preferred method on AWS. You just have to be aware that in this configuration the request between the ELB and the web server isn't actually over SSL so you have to check the header accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like req.protocol will always be 'http' on Amazon Web Services. Now im using:

```
req.get('x-forwarded-proto')
```

Comment: Your blanket statement about the request protocol always being 'http' on AWS is incorrect. It is correct if you have SSL termination happening on your load balancer, which it sounds like you do. Your load balancer is doing the SSL termination (because that's where you installed the SSL certificate), and always communicating with your server via http. There are several other ways to configure SSL, including termination on the web server, but since you are using SSL termination at the ELB you have to check the 'x-forwarded-proto' header.

Comment: Yeah you're right, ssl terminiation is happening on the ELB. Please enter that as an answer and i'll mark as correct